# Impossible to hide a Form from another Thread

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I have tried with Forms or Controls, but nothing works.

Two Forms on the main Thread (FrmMain ad FrmWait) ad another Thread that makes a long work.

FrmWait only displays a PictureBox with a "Downloading" animated gif. I want to Hide FrmWait from the Thread.

In FrmMain

```
    Private Sub StartThread()
        Debug.Print("Main ThreadId is: " & System.Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId)

        FrmWait.Show()
        Dim trd As New Thread(Sub()
                                  Flag.Agisci(Num, Value1, value2)
                              End Sub)
        trd.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub FrmMain_HandleCreated(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.HandleCreated
        Debug.Print("FrmMain Handle has been created: " & Me.Handle.ToString)
    End Sub
```

In FrmWait

```
   Private Delegate Sub CloseForm(hide As Boolean)
  
   Public Sub CloseWait(hide As Boolean)
        Debug.Print("******************* Entring in CloseWait")
        Try
            Dim h As IntPtr = Me.Handle
            Debug.Print("................... InvokeRequired is: " & Me.InvokeRequired.ToString & " on Handle: " & h.ToString)
            If Me.InvokeRequired Then
                Debug.Print("----------- Invoke is Required !!")
                Me.Invoke(New CloseForm(AddressOf CloseWait), hide)
            Else
                Debug.Print("+++++++++++ Calling Me.Visible = " & hide.ToString)
                Me.Visible = hide
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.Print(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub FrmWait_HandleCreated(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.HandleCreated
        Debug.Print("FrmWait Handle has been created: : " & Me.Handle.ToString)
    End Sub
```

In the Thread Class:

```
    Public Sub Agisci(Num As Integer, Value1 As String, Value2 As String)
        Try
            Debug.Print("Task ThreadId is: " & System.Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId)
            Sleep(2000)
            Throw New Exception("Foo")
      
            'some stuff bypassed by the exception

        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.Print(ex.Message)

            FrmWait.CloseWait(True)

            'this is another Form that is correctly displayed
            FrmMessBox.SetText(ex.Message)
            FrmMessBox.ShowDialog()
        End Try
    End Sub
```

The output:

> FrmMain Handle has been created: 4785876
> Main ThreadId is: 1
> FrmWait Handle has been created: 655546
> Task ThreadId is: 5
> Eccezione generata: 'System.Exception' in MyApp.exe -Foo
> ---------- Entring in CloseWait
> FrmWait Handle has been created: 917984
> ----------- InvokeRequired is: False on Handle: 917984 '****** FALSE?????
> +++++++++++ Calling Me.Visible = False '************* don't works!

Comment: This is a notorious bug in VB.NET programs, FrmWait.CloseWait() will create a *new* form when called from a worker thread.  It isn't visible, its Show() method wasn't called.  Use the `New` keyword to create an instance of FrmWait that can be used on both threads.

Comment: Note how you can actually see two instances of FrmWait getting created, "FrmWait Handle has been created" appears twice.  The second one is the trouble-maker.

Comment: You're using a default instance and they are thread-specific. Learn more [here](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/07/vbnet-default-form-instances.html).

Answer (score 0):

Following the answer of Hans Passant I have declared in a Module:

```
    Public FrmWait2 As New FrmWait
```

and I have changed FrmWait to FrmWait2 in the code. Now the debug reports:

> ---------- Entring in CloseWait
> +++++++++++ Invoke is Required !!  '**YES, now the other thread is visible**
> ---------- Entring in CloseWait
> +++++++++++ Calling Me.Visible = False

the code

```
    Debug.Print("------------ InvokeRequired is: " & 
              Me.InvokeRequired.ToString & " on Handle: " & Me.Handle.ToString)
```

BEFORE

```
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then.......
```

generates a "'System.InvalidOperationException'" for call from a different thread. :)

Why I had to correct the code in this absurd manner so to work is a real mistery.